# Getting -1 as a result from web service

Tags: android, web-services

I'm dealing with web services (wsdl, ksoap) on Android. After submitting the details (like username and password) to the server I am getting the value -1 as a response.

`Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));` is the line which I added to log the value

The logcat message is:

```
06-16 15:48:56.244: VERBOSE/HELLO(885): Trying to Login
06-16 15:48:57.454: VERBOSE/TAG(885): -1
```

After few corrections in the code I got the following message in logcat.

```
06-16 17:25:33.595: VERBOSE/HELLO(942): Trying to Login
06-16 17:25:40.034: VERBOSE/TAG(942): RegisterUserResponse{RegisterUserResult=-1; }
```

What does `-1` indicate? Is there any field not reaching the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative return value or status value generally indicates that something went wrong or that it is not the expected result.

It heavily depends on the web service implementation so there is probably no way to really tell what exactly went wrong. You'll have to consult the documentation of the API and web service your are using.

I'm very well aware that this is very generic answer but given that the question is just as generic I feel it is the only answer one can possibly provide.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean hi, consulting documentation of the API and web service is ok, but in what way we should initiate? I mean shall I consult the wsdl creator

Comment: Well I have no idea what web service you are working with. You should checkout the reference of the method that returns the result or of the web service itself. I don't know where that value comes from.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean thanks once again, some what better response i got from log cat now and its showing   06-16 17:25:33.595: VERBOSE/HELLO(942): Trying to Login
06-16 17:25:40.034: VERBOSE/TAG(942): RegisterUserResponse{RegisterUserResult=-1; }
 I m using WSDL ,ksoap i.e .net webservices

Comment: Example: _I have a problem with my car. I call my mechanic and tell him that I have a problem with my car. He asks me what car I drive and I tell him that it is a car with four wheels._ Do you think that the information helped the mechanic?

Comment: @JoeCullity: Thanks but I'm not the one having that problem. With my car example above I was trying to tell the OP that he should be more specific. ;)

Comment: @ Octavian Damiean Oops Sorry

Comment: @Raghu - Let me take a shot at this, Hi Raghu. The real info you need to solve this problem was probably logged into the web server you were trying to connect to. For security reasons, the only information your computer received was the -1 to let you know things didn't work. Try to contact your web service provider and see if they can send you their logs. If they can't, and your going to be doing serious web based development, you might want to change web hosting services. find someone who allows access to the events the server captures.

Comment: @Joe Cullity thanks a lot for the response, ya wat u said is correct and I should contact the web service provider